# why do i keep getting invalid get index 'rot_speed' on base GDscript

Tags: godot, gdscript

here is my code in the spinner script:

```
extends KinematicBody

var glob = preload("res://Glabal.gd")

var rotation_speed = glob.rot_sped

func _physics_process(delta):
    
    if rotation_speed == 300:
        rotation_speed -= 1 
    
    rotation_speed += 0.5
    
    rotate_y(deg2rad(rotation_speed * delta))
    
    print(rotation_speed)
```

here is my code in the global script and yes it is supposed to be glabal.gd:

```
extends Node

var rot_sped = 300
```

and here is my code in the settings script:

```
extends "res://Glabal.gd"

var glob = preload("res://Glabal.gd")

func _on_Increase_button_pressed():
    glob.rot_sped = glob.rot_sped + 1

func _on_Decrease_button_pressed():
    glob.rot_sped = glob.rot_sped - 1

func _process(delta):
    $"current speed/Label".text = "current rotation speed" + glob.rot_sped
```

Answer (score 1):

The file `"res://Glabal.gd"` is a script, more precisely a GDScript file.

So when you load it, for example like this:

```
var glob = preload("res://Glabal.gd")
```

You get a [`GDScript`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_gdscript.html) object. In fact, you can type it:

```
var glob:GDScript = preload("res://Glabal.gd")
```

The `GDScript` effectively represents a GDScript class. You can, for example, create an instance of it using [`new`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-new):

```
var glob:GDScript = preload("res://Glabal.gd")
var instance = glob.new()
```

What will be the type of the instance? Well, that GDScript file is the class. And - as the source code in that GDScript file says - it extends `Node`:

```
var glob:GDScript = preload("res://Glabal.gd")
var instance:Node = glob.new()
```

---

To answer the question the title. You are getting the error because `rot_speed` is not a property of `GDScript` (I remind you that you get a `GDScript` object from `preload("res://Glabal.gd")`). And thus this does not work:

```
var glob = preload("res://Glabal.gd")

var rotation_speed = glob.rot_sped
```

It might be a property of the instances of that particular script… But you don't have an instance of that particular script (which, again, you can create with `new`).

Anyway, if you instance your script with `new`, you are getting a new instance. Yet, I believe you want to get the same instance everywhere. So using `preload("res://Glabal.gd")` is wrong, I'll get back to that.

---

I don't know how you use your settings script, but it makes little sense to do this:

```
extends "res://Glabal.gd"

var glob = preload("res://Glabal.gd")
```

You are saying that your script extends the class in the file `"res://Glabal.gd"`, and it also has a reference to said class.

The settings script could access the properties on its parent class directly. However, we would be going down the wrong path.

Instead, write your settings script the way you will write anything else…

---

So, how? - You have a couple options:

- Make `"res://Glabal.gd"` an autoload (sigleton), with a name, for example `Global`. You can do that in Project Settings, on the AutoLoad tab.

  Then you can access it every where you need. For example:

  ```
  var rotation_speed = Global.rot_sped
  ```

  *Be aware that it is copying the value of `rot_sped` into the variable `rotation_speed`, so changes in `rot_sped` won't be reflected in `rotation_speed`.*
- Use resource based communication. For this, you are going to change the base type from `Node` to `Resource`. I also recommend giving it a name to the class, like this:

  ```
  class_name Global
  extends Resource

  var rot_sped = 300
  ```

  That defines a new `Resource` type called `Global`. And we are going to create a resource of that type. To do so, use the context menu on the FileSystem and choose `New Resource…`. Godot will ask you what kind of resource, and you pick `Global`. And save it.

  Then you will have a resource file. For example `"res://Global.tres`". That is what you `preload`:

  ```
  var glob = preload("res://Glabal.tres")
  ```

  And you can access it the way you intended:

  ```
  var glob = preload("res://Glabal.tres")

  var rotation_speed = glob.rot_sped
  ```

  And yes, you are going to get the same instance everywhere you use `preload("res://Glabal.tres")`. *That was also true for `preload("res://Glabal.gd")`, but that was an instance of `GDScript`, which is not what you want.*

  Here `glob` will be an instance of Global. In fact, you can type it:

  ```
  var glob:Global = preload("res://Glabal.tres")

  var rotation_speed = glob.rot_sped
  ```

Please notice that you need to configure autoloads in project settings, but not resources. Also notice that autoloads exist in the scene tree. Also they can be scenes, not just scripts. On the flip side, resources are not, and don't depend on, the scene tree. So there will be situations where one approach is preferible to the other. Although, for what you are doing so far, either way will work.